# Getting error while setting up Docusign with Salesforce, issues with permission

Tags: docusign

While setting up Docusign with Salesforce getting this error :
"There is an issue with your DocuSign account settings. The following permissions must all be enabled: 'Manage Account', 'Send Envelopes', 'Send on Behalf Of', and 'API Account Wide Access'. To update these settings, log in to DocuSign, select Preferences, then select Permissions"

Having issue with a particular production account of Docusign. Tried with other free or trial accounts and it works okay !

Docusign support is not that good the documentation I got related to this are outdated.

Any quick help is appreciated..